# Use Firebase Cloud firestore triggers from vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to get firebase-functions to work in vanilla JS (no node)?

The structure of my code is:

HTML:

```
</body>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.1.0/firebase-app.js"> </script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.1.0/firebase-functions.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.1.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

</html>
```

JS:

```
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "----------------------------------",
    authDomain: "----------.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://-----------.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "------------------",
    storageBucket: "------------------.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "------------------",
    appId: "------------------"
};


firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

I cannot seem to access the object exported by firebase-functions in order to add event handlers as outlined:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events

Could someone please give me insight into this?

Note: I am avoiding node.js because I am running this on a static Github Page.

Comment: Do you import the Firebase SDK somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up the client and server SDKs.

The client SDK that you've shown in the script include can only be used to invoke callable functions deployed to the Cloud Fucntions backend.

The server SDK can only be used to define functions that you deploy.  This code runs on the backend in response to events that occur in your project.

You can't use the client SDK to declare a function trigger like the one you're linking in the documentation.  If you want to query Firestore from a client, you should use the Firestore client SDK alone - you have no need for a Firestore trigger in Cloud Functions.

Comment: A Firestore trigger can **only** be defined using Cloud Functions as a backend.